# While loading audio cache delete what has already played

Tags: javascript, html, audio

While loading audio cache delete what has already played. Example: on a radio, buffering a 24hour .mp3/.ogg file can be HUGE, so my question is how can i delete the audio that has already played with javascript and html 5.

```
example
<audio controls>
<source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" >
<source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3" >
</audio>
```